# How to remove legacy link between docker containers

Tags: docker

My predecessor created 2 docker containers and linked them together using the --link option.

Now I have 1 live container that I want to continue using and the other is of no use. However, when I try to start one of them, I get

```
[keith@docker ~]$ sudo docker start ABC
Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /XYZ AS 
/ABC/XYZ
Error: failed to start containers: ABC
```

No help from here https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-remove-the-link-between-a-deleted-container-and-a-live-container/40431

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not run the image again into a new container?

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani, yes I can do that but I am curious if what I'm looking for is possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker has an `update` command which can be used to update settings of an existing container

```
$ docker update --help

Usage:  docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Update configuration of one or more containers

Options:
      --blkio-weight uint16        Block IO (relative
                                   weight), between 10 and
                                   1000, or 0 to disable
                                   (default 0)
      --cpu-period int             Limit CPU CFS (Completely
                                   Fair Scheduler) period
      --cpu-quota int              Limit CPU CFS (Completely
                                   Fair Scheduler) quota
      --cpu-rt-period int          Limit the CPU real-time
                                   period in microseconds
      --cpu-rt-runtime int         Limit the CPU real-time
                                   runtime in microseconds
  -c, --cpu-shares int             CPU shares (relative weight)
      --cpus decimal               Number of CPUs
      --cpuset-cpus string         CPUs in which to allow
                                   execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --cpuset-mems string         MEMs in which to allow
                                   execution (0-3, 0,1)
      --kernel-memory bytes        Kernel memory limit
  -m, --memory bytes               Memory limit
      --memory-reservation bytes   Memory soft limit
      --memory-swap bytes          Swap limit equal to
                                   memory plus swap: '-1' to
                                   enable unlimited swap
      --restart string             Restart policy to apply
                                   when a container exits
```

But you can't add or remove a link as you can see. You need to run a new container again. So in short what you are looking for is not possible

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I created a new container after all. Thank you for all the comments. Have a nice day!